# Replace last 9 delimeters "," with "|" in Unix

Tags: unix, replace

I want to replace last 9 "," delimeters with "|" in a file.

For example, from:

```
abcd,3,5,5,7,7,1,2,3,4
"ashu,pant,something",3,5,5,7,7,8,7,8,8,8
```

to:

```
abcd|3|5|5|7|7|1|2|3|4
"ashu,pant,something"|3|5|5|7|7|8|7|8|8|8
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I want to escape those comma which are inside double quotes and replace all comma with pipe

Comment: Please review this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace#159369. Also, this question will be better accepted on the Unix forum

Comment: Do you want to replace all commas except those inside double quotes, or do you want to replace the last 9?  Clarify your specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the same but replace all after the second occurrence with GNU sed:

```
$ echo \"ashu,pant\",3,5,5,7,7,87,8,8,8 |
  sed 's/,/|/2g'
"ashu,pant"|3|5|5|7|7|87|8|8|8
```

**Edit to match your changed requirements:**

Hackish, but first reverse lines and replace all commas with pipes, then replace pipes with commas starting from 10th occurrence:

```
$ echo -e \"ashu,pant\",3,5,5,7,7,87,8,8,8\\nabcd,3,5,5,7,7,1,2,3,4 |
  rev |
  sed 's/,/|/g; s/|/,/10g' |
  rev
"ashu,pant"|3|5|5|7|7|87|8|8|8
abcd|3|5|5|7|7|1|2|3|4
```

You could also use GNU awk and [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) to replace all comma outside of quotes:

```
$ echo -e \"ashu,pant\",3,5,5,7,7,87,8,8,8\\nabcd,3,5,5,7,7,1,2,3,4 | 
  awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")";OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1'
"ashu,pant"|3|5|5|7|7|87|8|8|8
abcd|3|5|5|7|7|1|2|3|4
```

Comment: I have 2 sets of records, one is without double quote and other is with double quote

Example:-
abcd,3,5,5,7,7,1,2,3,4
"ashu,pant,something",3,5,5,7,7,8,7,8,8,8

Result :-
abcd|3|5|5|7|7|1|2|3|4
"ashu,pant,something"|3|5|5|7|7|8|7|8|8|8

Comment: I want to replace all commas except those inside double quotes,

Comment: Thanks James Brown... It means alot to me.

Comment: Nice to hear. Please check that ✔ to accept my answer a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:digit:]]/," |&")gsub(/, /,"")}1' file

output
abcd|3|5|5|7|7|1|2|3|4
"ashu,pant,something"|3|5|5|7|7|8|7|8|8|8
```